# How to extract Sync Events for a particular call for daily reporting in sheet

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-taskrouter, twilio-conference, syncservices

I am using Twilio SDK and have developed an agent call system. I want to investigate missed calls for which I have enabled "Insights". What I want to ask is how can I extract "Sync Events" for a particular call for daily reporting. Also if someone can explain what are "Sync Events" that would be great.